# How does the these steps came?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm learning single variable calculus right now and at current about integration. I'm confused in a problem from sometime especially in two steps which I've circle. [image: Image 1]Please help. thankyou in advance.

Comment: I think there is a little typo it should be $x^2\cdot x^3(1+\frac{1}{x^4})^{3/4}$ in the denominator.

Comment: In the second step you mark, the $\frac{dx}{x^3}$ should be $\frac{dx}{x^5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to have an answer to this question. The two steps you mark are indeed wrong. As pointed out by @MrYouMath,
$$
(x^4+1)^{3/4}=(x^4(1+1/x^4))^{3/4}=x^3(1+1/x^4)^{3/4}.
$$
So there is a factor of $x^3$ missing.

In the second step, the $x^3$ should be $x^5$.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is wrong:
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2(x^4+1)^{3/4}}=\int{\frac{dx}{x^2(x^4(1+\frac{1}{x^4}))^{3/4}}}=\int{\frac{dx}{x^2\cdot (x^4)^{3/4}(1+\frac{1}{x^4})^{3/4}}}=\int{\frac{dx}{x^5(1+\frac{1}{x^4})^{3/4}}}$$